# IE: jQuery loaded content with iFrame - iFrame does not show

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a page, that loads in content from another page, with jQuery. Like so:-

```
$('#link_help').live('click', function() {
    $('#helpBox').load('content.php?load=helpBox');
});
```

This content includes some static HTML and an iFrame. This loads perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox.

However, Internet Explorer (testing on 9) is loading the HTML content, but not the iFrame src. I can change the colour of the iframe, play with it. But, I can not use or change the src.

Any ideas?

Comment: hmmm, did you try with modernizr ?

Comment: well it's not possible to read the src from an iframe, can you show the code where you are setting the iframe src, or maybe post the html page ?

Comment: also once you load that in IE, what's the src of the iframe? Is it just blank? Can you put it in a http://www.jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I can get the src of the iframe, and I can actually change it - just doesnt appear. The HTML in the src can be ANYTHING. It doesn't show. I realise it's not ideal not seeing it, I'll try and get out of closed dev

Comment: I've stripped everything out so only iframe is in the html being loaded in. Still blank iframe in IE.

Comment: I've now injected the loaded content with an iframe with $('divImFilling').html('<iframe src="src" width="blah" height="blah"></iframe>'); still nothing in IE, everything else ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. Incase anyone has this problem. Check whether you're on an HTTPS connection.

This was my problem. By default, IE9 does not allow iframes to be loaded into HTTPS environment, which are HTTP. I've now requested HTTPS and it's fixed.